# The best way to get rid from SNAPSHOT version in the dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, cloudera, dependency-management

I want to use dependency from the Cloudera Maven repository:
Extract from my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/cloudera-repos/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0-cdh4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It depends on parent "spark-parent" that referenced to parent with SNAPSHOT version.

Extract from spark-parent pom.xml (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/spark/spark-parent/0.9.0-cdh4.6.0/):

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.cloudera.cdh</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdh-root</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0-cdh4.6.0</version>
```

When I run simple "mvn clean package" I have the error that this SNAPSHOT artifact cannot be found.

What is the simplest way to solve this? A solution must be a change in pom.xml or in the build command. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using Maven Central? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10

Comment: Unfortunately I need cloudera's version of spark library

Comment: Download the jar from any other site and install it into your local repo as <groupId>com.cloudera.cdh</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdh-root</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: Marco, Sorry, I give wrong problem set. I need to build this project not only on my computer. This walkaround is like a hack. I need to change pom.xml or change build command to solve this problem.

Comment: @Tunaki `mvnrepository` is not [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) URL for access is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ ....

Answer (score 0):

The Cloudera Maven repository [doesn't have](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/com/cloudera/cdh/cdh-root/) the artifact `com.cloudera.cdh:cdh-root:pom:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT`, therefore you won't be able to build your project using it.

However, you can use the Spring cache of this repository: `http://repo.spring.io/cloudera-cache`. It [contains](http://repo.spring.io/cloudera-cache/com/cloudera/cdh/cdh-root/4.6.0-SNAPSHOT/) the missing artifacts. You will also have to enable snapshot dependencies inside your repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera-cache</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/cloudera-cache/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```